# Android custom Dialog not showing after FragmentActivity recreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

On my app i have a ViewPager inside FragmentActivity that contain a fragments. In one of that fragment (called FragOne) i have a button that on tap open a custom Dialog (a Class extends android.app.Dialog) on certain position of screen:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MyCustomDialog = new MyCustomDialog(getContext());
                    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
                    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());
                    dialog.show();    
                    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
                    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(myWidth, myHeight);
                }
            });
```

When user perform some action on dialog some tasks are executed, recreate() of FragmentActivity is called, then dialog dismiss itself. 
Now happen that if try to open again the dialog by press the button, i can't see it anymore. For make dialog appear i need to go to change viewpager current visible fragment, then go back to FragOne.
How can i do for let open dialog again without change fragment and go back to FragOne?

Comment: I think if you create the onClickListener by name like: onClickLestener myListener = new...  then you can remove the listener in the onDetach() method.  If this works let me know so I can write an official answer? Thanks.